# How to do a SYSTEM rollback manually

Tags: backend, error, backup

this morning I did a system backup (backend -> system -> tools -> backup) of my store because I wanted to try some extensions and now my site is ruined.
I've stored the backup on local, so how can I make the rollback? I have to overwrite all my magento installation  with the backup ?

I can't access to the admin panel, so if any one knows for sure how to make the rollback manually with the system backup I'll appreciate it so much.

Thanks.

EDIT: I solved the problem that had ruined my store. It was appearing error 503 and lot of errors from the processor.php file. I've deleted the maintenance.flag file from root dir, and now works.
Anyway If you want to answer the question in order to help other people that needs to do that, you're free to do.

Comment: Add an answer to your question with what you did, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Marius well ok, but my answer it isn't the exactly answer for the question. But's ok. At first I needed to do a rollback but later I solved the problem that ruined my store, so now I don't need to rollback it.

Comment: It's not important if it answers your question. It's important that is solved your issue. maybe other people will have the same problem and can solve it the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem that had ruined my store. It was appearing error 503 and lot of errors from the processor.php file. I've deleted the maintenance.flag file from root dir, and now works.

So the rollback isn't needed.

Thanks for your time.